# Custom URI Scheme in Windows App Works in Dev but Not Microsoft App Store

Tags: windows, flutter, uri, msix, microsoft-store

I have built a Flutter app for Windows and have implemented a custom URI scheme so that when users hit an authentication redirect URL, it sends them back to my app.

```
myapp://auth#token=abc
```

I am using the [protocol_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/protocol_handler) package and have implemented everything so that it works on my development machine (Windows 11).

```dart
import 'package:protocol_handler/protocol_handler.dart';

void main() async{
  await protocolHandler.register('myapp'); //Not my real URI 
}
```

I can also build an `MSIX` package, sign it on my computer, and it still works.

When I click a `myapp://` link, my web browser (Chrome or Edge) asks me if I want to open my app. I say "yes" and my app is brought to the foreground and handles the redirect's contents.

I submitted my app to the Microsoft App Store and set this capability in the Partner Center:

```
runFullTrust
```

But I keep getting **rejected because the custom URI won't open my app and the tester can't sign in**.

Is there some other capability my app needs to make this work in a production environment? I know my app needs to make registry edits in order for the URI to work. Do I have to explicitly request that somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out. The protocol has to be added to the [msix](https://pub.dev/packages/msix) build you generate in your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
# Windows App Store Configuration `dart run msix:create`
msix_config:
  #######################################
  msix_version: 1.2.3.0 # Last number is always 0
  #######################################
  display_name: App Name
  publisher_display_name: Company Name
  identity_name: company.app 
  publisher: CN=XXXXXX... # This is found in your app info in the MS Partner dashboard
  logo_path: C:\Users\You\Desktop\FlutterApp\assets\images\windows.png
  store: true
  #Custom URI
  protocol_activation: myapp # <-- This is the critical part I was missing!
```